# How automate creating videos in Blender?

Tags: python, blender

How can I solve this task using Blender and Python: needs automaticly create video of titles having text,video and timing (list of time cutoffs) at input. I mean we do script which gives Blender input data (text,timing,etc) and Blender render a video with a template which he has. 
The question is can I do it with Blender API and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty vague question. Do you have an example of what you're trying to do?

Conceptually, the simple answer is yes. Consider the following problem:

> I need to create a small video that circles around a single object

To accomplish this, you would create a script that would:

1. Create an cube at 0,0,0
2. Add a camera to the scene and zoom to the selected object (the cube)
3. Change the location / rotation of the camera
4. Create a keyframe on location / rotation of the object on a frame in the future
5. Repeat 3 & 4 until camera goes full circle (this can be done through looping)
6. Set render parameters on the camera
7. Render the scene

All of the above can be done via python scripting. You can learn how to invoke all the methods above by reading the api documentation [Here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/). There is also a lot of resources available at the [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/).

I hope this helps. This is the best I can do with the limited information provided.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will try to explore blender api docs and than return to the task